# Even though item is not selected OnItemSelected is getting triggered in Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have the following code for the spinner. I am not getting any errors and spinner is working but I am having a problem with this even though I have not selected any item, the code inside the onItemSelected listener is getting executed, but I do not want this to happen n till I select and item from spinner. Please any of you let me know why is this happening. Thanks a lot. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

My spinner code:

```
SQLiteDataBaseAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataBaseAdapter(this);

        Cursor cursor = adapter.getAllSubTaskData();

        // Log.d("Pana", "The value of cursor is " +Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cursor.toString())));

        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{SQLiteHelper.UID, SQLiteHelper.SUB_TASK_NAME};
        int[] toViewIds = new int[]{R.id.textViewUID, R.id.textViewSubTaskName};

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.custom_spinner_subtask_row, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIds, 0);

        subTaskList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);


        subTaskList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "The position of the item clicked is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("position", Long.toString(id));
                editor.commit();



                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SubTaskDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", Long.toString(id));  //position starts from 0, but in db row starts from 1
                startActivity(intent);


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

This complete code of spinner I have written in onCreate() method of my activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default functionality of the spinner. Spinner will select the 0th position when the adapter is bind to it

If you really want to prevent it on initialization, so do it in this manner inside onitemselected

```
check=check+1 
if(check>1) {
    // put your code
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's not triggering initially but after I click item present at position 0 its not getting executed till I select an item present other than position 0.

Comment: Is there a way to counter this? I have initialised check to 0.

Comment: Have you come across any widget other spinner which I can make use of?